# How to create a v-toolbar with fixed width content

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

Basically I took this, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/googleContacts.

I don't like float containers, I want everything to fit into usual fixed-width centered v-container on a large screen. That's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

But I met a number of obstacles with toolbar: it's float but it's content is centered and has fixed width. I pasted v-container inside v-toolbar, but it was not centered since v-toolbar__content > *:first-child and last-child have margin:0. Then added v-flex before v-container and that caused height collapse so the v-toolbar buttons were not occupy full toolbar height anymore. Then added v-layout to expand height and some v-flex inside but still haven't got any success. The question is how to properly work with v-toolbar and v-container to make the toolbar's content fixed width and centered.

Comment: CodePen? Example code? Anything?

Answer (score 1):

Apply to v-toolbar this style:

```
<v-toolbar :class="{ 'my-toolbar': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown }"> </v-toolbar>
<style>
 .my-toolbar { width: 80%; left:  10%; } 
</style>
```

You will have to play a bit with the % to keep it inline with v-container elements. You can also look into a computed property to check different breakpoints.